# Polymer: How to set a Default Value for paper-tabs with Nested Properties

Tags: javascript, polymer

I want to set a **default value** for the selected item of my `paper-tabs`.

It works fine, if I write the selected property it like this:

```
<paper-tabs selected="{{tabname}}"
            attr-for-selected="key">
    <paper-tab key="foo">Foo</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab key="bar">Bar</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab key="baz">Baz!</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```

But I would like to use nested properties like that:

```
<paper-tabs selected="{{data.tabname}}"
            attr-for-selected="key">
    <paper-tab key="foo">Foo</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab key="bar">Bar</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab key="baz">Baz!</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```

These are my properties:

```
properties: {
    data: {
        type: Object,
        value: function () {
            return {                    
                tabname: {
                    type: String,
                    value: 'foo'
                }
            }
        },
    }
}
```

And here is the functioning Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/GRrJh0p2s9uReLnC3Ze7?p=preview

I'd like it to be set by default to `key`, the first `div` in the index. Anyone knows why my plnkr is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that creating properties in objects work that way in Polymer. Doing something like this works:

```
properties: {
    data: {
        type: Object,
        value: function () {
            return {                    
                tabname: 'foo'
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
properties: {
    data: {
        type: Object,
        value: {                    
            tabname: 'foo'
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: For Arrays and objects always use a function to return the default value otherwise you will run into issues when you instantiate multiple instances of that element